# Unable to connect RDP while using static ip

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

So I am trying to connect to IIS server through remote desktop connection. When I try to connect using my mobile hotspot, the connection is successful. But when I try to connect, while my laptop is connected to LAN, the connection is unsuccessful. Things I want to let you know about my LAN connection is, I use a static IP and local DNS servers to connect to the network and that is the only way to connect. I cannot use public DNS servers.

and I am sure that my static IP is not conflicting with any other machine on my network. I tried connect to RDP using IP,domain name. The connection was unsuccessful  in both the cases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to connect to my remote server using both IP and DNS name. neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check RDP port from your laptop to iis server is not filtered. This could be the reason you are not able to RDP from LAN.

To check this you can use port query tool.

Comment: got this "TCP port 3389 (ms-wbt-server service): LISTENING

UDP port 3389 (ms-wbt-server service): LISTENING or FILTERED"

Comment: Type in run box >> mstsc /admin

Comment: @Tim_Stewart i cant comment because of points. So post as answer.

Comment: @AnuragGawande still the same.... stuck "configuring remote session"